# Как дать доступ к переменным сессии в пакете только определенным блокам кодa?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Есть такая структура пакетов:

```
create or replace package packvals as
    val1 int;
end;
/
create or replace package packfunc as
    function getVal return int;
    procedure setVal (v int);
end;
/
create or replace package body packfunc is
    function getVal return int is begin 
        return packvals.val1; 
    end;
    procedure setVal (v int) is begin 
        packvals.val1 := v;   
    end;
end;
/
```

Переменные сессии хранятся в отдельном пакете. В данный момент, эти переменые доступны в любом участке кода выполняемого в сессии.

Например, мой коллега работает над реализацией части логики в других пакетах и может ошибочно воспользоваться теми же переменными. Чисто схематически это можно представить так:

```
create or replace procedure starter is 
begin
    packfunc.setVal (0);
    /** some logic [...] 
    some_package. */ packvals.val1 := 101;
    /** more logic [...] */
    if packfunc.getVal () < 100 then
        dbms_output.put_line ('expected behaviour for '||packfunc.getVal);
        packfunc.setVal (packfunc.getVal () + 1);
    else
        dbms_output.put_line ('unexpected behaviour due to '||packfunc.getVal);
    end if;
end;
/
exec starter
```

> unexpected behaviour due to 101

Поэтому, хочу дать доступ к этим переменным только моему пакету.

Как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с версии 12c можно более гранулированно управлять доступом к определённым блокам кода, даже если они определены в одной схеме. Подробне об этом в главе [ACCESSIBLE BY Clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/ACCESSIBLE-BY-clause.html#GUID-9720619C-9862-4123-96E7-3E85F240FF36).

Пример в вопросе надо изменить так:

```
create or replace package packvals 
accessible by (package packfunc, function getVal, procedure setVal) as
    val1 int;
end;
/
```

Больше воспользоваться переменной `val1` без пакета `packfunc` никто не посмеет:

```
create or replace procedure some_proc is
begin
     packvals.val1 := 101;   
end;
/
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
3/6       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
3/6       PLS-00904: insufficient privilege to access object PACKVALS

begin
    packvals.val1 := 101;
end;
/
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00904: insufficient privilege to access object PACKVALS
```