# Как дать доступ к атрибутам объектного типа только методам это типа?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, права-доступа

В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178653/217579) шла речь о доступе к переменным сессии определённых в пакете.
В приведённой там документации на [ACCESSIBLE BY Clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/ACCESSIBLE-BY-clause.html#GUID-9720619C-9862-4123-96E7-3E85F240FF36), сказанно, что она доступна также для пользовательских типов `TYPE`. Но примеров нет.

Пробую так дать доступ к атрибутам типа только методам этого типа:

```
create or replace type privT  
accessible by (type privT, function getval, procedure setval) is object (
    value varchar2 (8),
    member procedure setval (self in out privT, v varchar2),
    member function getval return varchar2
    ) instantiable final
/
Type PRIVT compiled

create or replace type body privT is
    member procedure  setval (self in out privT, v varchar2) is begin 
        self.value := v; 
    end;
    member function getval return varchar2 is begin 
        return self.value; 
    end;
end;    
/ 
Type Body PRIVT compiled
```

Всё компилируется, но не могу создать даже неинициализированную переменную этого типа:

```
declare
    p privT;
begin null; 
end;
/
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PLS-00904: insufficient privilege to access object PRIVT
```

Какое тут может быть решение?

Answer (score 2):

Авторизованный доступ может получить, цитата из документации:

> *unit_kind* **accessor** *[schema.]unit_name*
> Each accessor specifies **another PL/SQL entity** that may access the
> entity which includes the ACCESSIBLE BY clause.

Нельзя дать доступ самому себе, это должен быть другой объект БД. Причём, доступ можно дать только всему объекту: пакету, типу данных, а не их методам, функциям или процедурам.

Можно инкапсулировать объектный тип данных в другой, и переместить все методы туда:

```
create or replace type privT accessible by (type publT) is object (value varchar2 (8))
/ 
create or replace type publT force as object (
    priv privT,
    constructor function publT (v varchar2) return self as result,  
    member function get return varchar2,
    member function setnew (self in out publT, v varchar2) return publT)
/
create or replace type body publT as
    constructor function publT (v varchar2) return self as result is begin
        self.priv := privT (v);
        return;
    end;
    member function get return varchar2 is begin
        return priv.value;
    end;
    member function setnew (self in out publT, v varchar2) return publT is begin
        priv.value := v; 
        return self;
    end;
end;
/
```

Теперь доступ только возможен через инкапсулирующий тип данных:

```
var rc refcursor
declare
    --v privT; --insufficient privilege
    v1 publT := publT ('val1');
    v2 publT; 
begin null;
    --v1.priv.value := 'val2'; --insufficient privilege
    v2 := v1.setnew ('val2');
    open :rc for select v1.get () value, v2 v2 from dual;  
end;
/

V1       V2(PRIV(VALUE))                 
-------- --------------------------------
val2     PUBLT(PRIVT('val2'))
```